# Changing web.config unloads ASP.NET application, but doesn't unload "enough"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, interop, c++-cli

We have an ASP.NET web application, which is a **C# DLL**, that references a **C++/CLI DLL**, that links against some native static libs.

When we edit the web.config file, the appdomain unloads itself as expected, however at the next web request the application crashes with some access violation exception from our native code.

Further investigation has shown that as soon when the app domain "unloads", the **w3wp.exe process actually lives on**, and it only unloads our C# DLL (and *not* our C++/CLI DLL). This is probably why we're getting these exceptions.

How can we stop this madness? Can we get ASP.NET to completely recycle the w3wp process upon web.config update? Can we get ASP.NET to actually unload all of our DLLs if w3wp lives on?

Comment: In the meanwhile, until we can either solve these exceptions and/or the incomplete unload, our workaround is to catch these exceptions with a VEH, which we have for minidumps anyway. The handler produces a dump and then exits the process, which causes IIS to open up a new process (this way no web request fails!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any solution better than calling `Environment.Exit(0)` at the end of `Application_End`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper assembly and manually GetModuleHandle + FreeLibrary when the assembly / appDomain is recycled.

It would cause problems if you create Application Domains manually or use one Application Pool in IIS for multiple applications, though.

Comment: Wrapper assembly around what?

Comment: A "FreeDll" Wrapper (in C#) around whatever DLL is not getting freed (for convenience).